# Overbar over range of possible values

Tags: notation

In a research paper I stumbled upon the formula $x =\overline{0 \dots 2^n-1}$. As far as I understand from the context of the paper this means that $x$ can have a value between $0$ and $2^n - 1$, but what does the overline mean?

Comment: Possibly that the end points are included, i.e. $x$ is allowed to be $0$ or $2^n-1$? I have never seen it before, so I have no idea. What was the research paper?

Comment: This notation was much more common 100 years ago.  Back in the days before things like $\{\;\dots\;\}$ notation for sets.